# Broken oh-my-posh on Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal (Preview) with oh-my-posh. But when I start my terminal up, the screen is broken as hell.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here, and no worries - I didn't quite know what was on-topic and not when I started out either.  Two years into using these sites, and it can still be tough to figure out some times ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Oh My Posh user myself, but it sounds like you are running into [this problem](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/faq#windows-terminal-unexpected-space-between-segmentstext) mentioned in the Oh My Posh FAQ.

It sounds like it's due to an issue (or missing feature) in Windows Terminal.  The way I'm reading it, I may have run into it with some glyphs in WSL2 with the Fish shell.

If that is what you are seeing, the Oh My Posh FAQ recommends a workaround of adding an invisible spacing character at the end of each segment.  For example:

```
{
    "type": "executiontime",
    /* other attributes here */
    "properties": {
    "always_enabled": true,
    "prefix": "\ufbab",
    "postfix": "\u2800" // invisible spacing character
    }
}
```

I believe you'll need to do this for each element of your prompt.